# Debug android application in android tablet

Tags: android, tablet

Now I am developing one android application. I am running my code in emulateor. Can anyone help me How to debug my own android application in android tablet(Matrix One) instead of android emulator (i.e) steps to configure my android tablet(Matrix One) with eclipse?

Thanks,
Manoj.

Comment: Guide here http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable USB Debugging from your settings (and mock locations if you need them)
2. Plug the device into the computer via USB
3. Use eclipse to run the app on the device
4. You're done

[This](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) part of the documentation has more details on doing this, like installing drivers, configuring UDev etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might need a additional driver. You should be able to download it via the sdk.
Once the driver installed, just plug in your device after turning on the debug modus on the tablet under `Application-Development`. Your device should appear in the device view in eclipse. The Application should automatically be launched on the real device once plugged in.